# Integer.class and int.class

Tags: java

How does this Java statement compile without warnings?

```
Class<Integer> x = int.class;
```

even though

```
Integer.class != int.class
```

**Edit:** Putting it a different way, it seems as though `Integer.class` and `int.class` have nothing in common (see comments below), so why does it make sense for this assignment to be possible?

Comment: the declaration of `int.class` is: `public static final Class<Integer> TYPE = (Class<Integer>) Class.getPrimitiveClass("int");` Since the type parameter doesn't truly matter and it's boxed, it's passable.

Comment: @bestsss: The value is boxed but other properties of the class do not hold. For example, one can use reflection to construct an `Integer` using `Integer.class` but there is no way to do this with `int.class`.

Comment: you can't construct an `int` at all via reflection, it's a primitive. The decision is quite simple: the primitives are boxed, so anywhere you can pass an int, an Integer would do (or vice verse). There is one exception though: simple class parameters are totally different, reflection like `getMethod("xxx", Integer.class)` won't work for `xxx(int x)`.

Comment: I do understand that primitives are different, which is why this seems awkward. `int.class` is neither a superclass nor a subclass of `Integer.class`, `Integer.class.isAssignableFrom(int.class) == false` and `int.class.cast(0)` throws a `ClassCastException`. I don't see anything that can be done using `int.class` that relates to `Class<Integer>`.

Comment: Class is final (and doesn't have subclasses), the param type's only a compile time magic, it's lost during runtime and the boxing allows interoperability between primitives and wrappers. Since param types cannot be primitives the box class is used. That's all. For the record, I believe autoboxing was unnecessary and most of generic (aside co-variant return types) didn't improve the language, in 20++ years programming I've had 2 times "ClassCastException": once b/c using add instead of addAll, i.e. autocomplete, and the other due to wrong import. Typing all the `<...>` just make code unreadable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a whole lot of searching, I came across this little snippet in the JLS, [section 15.8.2 Class Literals](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.8.2):

> If p is the name of a primitive type, let B be the type of an expression of type p after boxing conversion (§5.1.7). Then the type of p.class is Class<B>.

The spec doesn't explain why this is so, instead of `Class<?>` for example. I have also been unable to find any evidence that this is related to either generics or autoboxing.

`Integer` is a first-class object whereas `int` is a primitive type, and most methods of `Class` such as `isInstance`, `isAssignableFrom` and `cast` which operate on `Object`s are invalid in the context of `int.class`. Consequently, I do not see any reason why the type of `int.class` is `Class<Integer>`.

Answer (score 4):

Due to [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html). You can't use primitives in as type parameters, so the primitive is boxed into the wrapper.

Comment: Don't see why that would require autoboxing to work on class literals as well, though.

Comment: It looks like a workaround, because you can't have Class<int>. Of course, you can use `Class<?>`

Comment: Indeed seems like a hack, and I don't see any reason why `Class<?>` wouldn't suffice. See my comment above -- `Integer.class` and `int.class` aren't even similar as one might expect.

Comment: @Bozho, if you use Class<?> you can't declare anything like `<T> T <Class<T>)`

Comment: @bestsss: In what scenario is this useful for `int.class`? There is no way to return a primitive `int` for a generic return type.

Comment: @casablanca, but you can do int `int n=xxx(int.class)`, the signature is oversimplistic, yet it might be `(Class<T> clazz, T x)` and be called like `xxx(int.class, 10)`.

Comment: @bestsss: You cannot pass primitives for generic types. The 10 in your example is autoboxed into an `Integer` and not passed as an `int`.

Comment: @casablanca, neither the return type is an 'int', the reason is to keep an interoperability, the point is you cant do that if int.class was Class<?>

Comment: @bestsss: Interoperability with what, though? I don't see a situation where one would explicitly want to pass `int.class` when dealing with generics anyway. If you can post an answer with an example showing how this may be of use, I will gladly accept your answer.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe this has anything to do with autoboxing.

This is part of the rules of generics that it treats primitive types as their wrappers.

Comment: Is this specified somewhere in the JLS?